# Regex expression for string matching

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to match my string with `"*B*[XXX]"`.
So for example it could be `"MB0[23]"` or `"DB50.DBB152[128]"`. At this moment, it's too complicated for me.

Please help.

Comment: Tomaszu, your requirements are not clear. Also, you need to try something yourself *before* posting the question. Go try on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com). And the best regex reference is at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: Could you explain what format do you want and provide *positive* as well as *negative* examples? Why, e.g., `"MB0[23]"` is *positive* one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right from your example, your format has to contain a capital B and brackets with numbers in it.
Try to use one of these:

This for strings that contain a "B" and brackets after it (with optional contents):

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(65535);
string format = @"/(?:[\0-" + c + @"]+)?B(?:[\0-" + c + @"]+)?\[(?:[\0-" + c + @"]+)?\]/";
```

This for strings that contain a "B" and brackets after it with numbers or nothing in it:

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(65535);
string format = @"/(?:[\0-" + c + @"]+)?B(?:[\0-" + c + @"]+)?\[(?:\d+)?\]/";
```

This for strings that contain a "B" and brackets after it with numbers in it:

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(65535);
string format = @"/(?:[\0-" + c + @"]+)?B(?:[\0-" + c + @"]+)?\[(?:\d+)\]/";
```

This should match both examples you provided.
You can check it and learn this format easily here: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

This will select both of your examples, but unfortunately with such little to work with, I can't be certain that this is what you want.

`/\wB\d+(?:\.\w{3}\d+)?\[\d+\]/` should give you what you want.

With this regex, `MB0[23]` will be returned, as well as all of `DB50.DBB152[128]`.

Hope this solves your problem!